# Golang Binary Search Tree Algorithm Translation

Tags: go, reference, tree, binary-search-tree

I'm beginner to Golang and trying to build a Binary Search Tree. My source code to do it:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

type Node struct{
    value int
    left *Node
    right *Node
}

func insert(root *Node,v int){
    if root==nil{
        root=&Node{v,nil,nil}
    } else if v<root.value{
        insert(root.left,v)
    } else{
        insert(root.right,v)
    }
}

func inTraverse(root *Node){
    if (root==nil){
        return
    }
    inTraverse(root.left)
    fmt.Printf("%d",root.value)
    inTraverse(root.right)
}

func main() {
    var treeRoot *Node
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    n:=6
    var a[6]int
    for i:=0;i<n;i++{
        a[i]=rand.Intn(20)+1
    }
    fmt.Println("Array of integer: ")
    for i:=0;i<n;i++{
        fmt.Printf("%d ",a[i])
    }
    fmt.Println()
    for i:=0;i<n;i++{
        insert(treeRoot,a[i])
    }
    inTraverse(treeRoot)
    fmt.Println()
}
```

The result shows an empty tree. What's wrong with my code? Does Golang have pass-by-value or pass-by-reference? Please help me solve this.

Comment: Please do not ask for tutorials or off-site references on Stack Overflow. This will invariably lead to your question being closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go always passes parameters by value. You should rather write:

```
func insert(root *Node,v int) *Node {
    if root == nil{
        root = &Node{v,nil,nil}
    } else if v<root.value{
        root.left = insert(root.left,v)
    } else{
        root.right = insert(root.right,v)
    }
    return root
}
```

and:

```
for i:=0;i<n;i++{
    treeRoot = insert(treeRoot,a[i])
}
```

See the result at: http://play.golang.org/p/94H_l3rfSH